# Votos negativos em uma resposta válida?

Tags: debate

Recentemente respondi a uma **[pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127925/menu-centralizado/)** no Stack Overflow em Português, fiz a resposta de acordo com a pergunta, visando ajudar o máximo possível e era bem simples até, porém recebi -1 na hora e agora recebi outro -1 e o mais importante, os dois votos negativos sem nenhuma justificativa ou comentário para que eu pudesse arrumar ou melhorar, sei la.

O curioso é que a própria pessoa que fez a pergunta deixou um comentário.

> Ow obrigado vou pesquisar sobre esse nav, e deu o visual perfeito que eu estava querendo vlw amigo

Aparentemente nem ele deu +1, muito menos marcou como resposta correta.

Isso é justo? Responder uma pergunta de forma correta, ajudar o op e ser glorificado com votos negativos?

*Novos usuários deveriam ser manipulados* * para que aprendessem a utilizar o Stack Overflow tanto em PT quanto em outros idiomas. Isso não é a primeira vez que acontece comigo, outras vezes respondi de forma correta e mesmo assim nada de +1 ou ser marcado como resposta correta.

**Agradeço muito o seu obrigado**, mas vocês sabem que quem responde uma pergunta aqui no SoPT *muitas vezes, se não sempre* prefere +1 na resposta do que um agradecimento de quem é ajudado.

Acredito que isso seja um desabafo, junto com a dúvida de que será que tem alguma coisa errada com a resposta?

São com esses acontecimentos que fazem eu apoiar votos negativos somente com justificativa.

Comment: Essa etapa na minha vida de SOPT passou, graças a Deus. Os conselhos de @Lbotinely  me ajudaram bastante,kkk

Comment: É tão bom quando abre uma pergunta no meta sobre votos negativos e justamente nessa pergunta você também recebe um voto negativo e o mais legal é que também sem justificativa. Parece que isso é uma perseguição kk

Comment: Não fui eu, já vou avisando... Mas eu sei o que rola, já aconteceu comigo. teve uma época que as coisas estavam feias, eu recebia negativos em todas perguntas, mas se quer um sábio conselho: Deixa para lá. No final das contas, os moderadores fizeram justiça e os votos negativos sumiram de quase todas as perguntas (demorou muitos meses, mas eles fizeram um bom trabalho)

Comment: Vou seguir seu conselho @WallaceMaxters, se ficar com isso na cabeça acaba desmotivando, o importante é saber que pelo menos eu estou tentando ajudar independente de qualquer coisa, além disso, sendo ajudado. Obrigado ;)

Comment: Minha primeira resposta no meta com muitos pontos, uma lição de vida... kkkkkkk

Comment: Que bom que você gostou das respostas! Mas a melhor forma de agradecer quem te ajudou é assinalando a melhor resposta e votando em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil pra todo mundo.

Comment: Aqui "só" vejo 1 downvote. Não ligues, há sempre alguém disposto a dar -1 a troco de nada, o segredo é não ligar.

Comment: Quero ver quando a alteração acontecer, onde será possível todos verem o autor do voto... Aí muita coisa ficará clara...

Comment: @MagicHat, que *alteração* é essa? Por acaso o Yahoo!Respostas vai comprar a Stack Overflow?

Comment: @brasofilo pq vc é contra, que seja visível os autores dos votos contra e a favor ?

Comment: @MagicHat desculpa me intrometer mas, ele não disse que é contra, apenas perguntou que atualização é essa (que eu também não sei) em que será possível visualizar autores de votos tanto a favor quanto contra.

Comment: Sério ? No meu comentário, está a resposta da minha afirmação..."Onde será possível ver os autores dos votos"... Agora os 5w é outra história(Who, Why,What, When, Where),  @VictorGomes, você é a diferença entre um comentário educado,  e os Ironistas de plantão...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Meu amigo, um sábio conselho a se seguir: Continue fazendo a sua parte para ajudar o site.

Se alguém realmente está perseguindo você, ignore. Se de fato há perseguição, o intuito é ganhar a sua atenção (de maneira negativa).

Creio que o Stack Overflow é uma comunidade muito organizada e, se houver alguma irregularidade, a mesma será corrigida.

Lembre-se que os pontos negativos as vezes são dados legitimamente, porém, pelo fato de alguns usuários serem imaturos (digo, no sentido de não aceitar o Downvote e querer fazer "vingancinha"), acaba que deixam o usuário com medo de deixar o motivo pelo qual negativou.

Frequentemente, eu costumo negativar umas respostas/perguntas ruins, mas quando percebo que o usuário não aceita crítica (quando já fui duramente criticado ou maltratado por exemplo), simplesmente deixo de comentar.

Discutir não costuma valer a pena, você pode estar gastando um tempo útil para responder outra pergunta e ajudar uma pessoa.

Esse é um sábio conselho de alguém que já foi um "reclamão dos votos negativos recebidos" (coitado do @Gabe, ouviu tanta falação na cabeça), mas no final, depois de muitos e muitos conselhos, e repensar que não valia a pena esquentar com isso, deixei de lado.

No final das contas, mesmo que eu já tivesse recebido uns -50, de tantos negativos que eu recebia, acabou que os votos negativos simplesmente sumiram.

Isso me faz acreditar que: Se alguém faz coisa errada, colherá o que plantou. Comunidades sérias não costumam aceitar esse tipo de comportamento. Aqui é sério.

Acalme-se e lembre-se de que a justiça pode ser​ lenta, mas ela vem a qualquer hora.

E não interprete os negativos sempre como perseguição por causa do comportamento de 2 ou 3, porque senão você terá olhos maus, e julgará usuários com boas intenções. Aí você é quem estará errado :)

Espero que isso te acalme, meu filho :)

Aconselho também ler pelo menos a última frase dessa resposta:

https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1247/4995

Comment: Bom saber que existe pessoas sempre apoiando quem faz o certo. A pergunta aqui no META foi mais um desabafo e valeu a pena. Vou continuar tentando ajudar o site da maneira que posso, até porque muitas das vezes, eu aprendo mais respondendo do que perguntando haha

Comment: Acabei de dar -1 "mas quando percebo que o usuário não aceita crítica (quando já fui duramente criticado ou maltratado por exemplo), simplesmente deixo de comentar.". Não deixem de fazer o bem por causa de uns -1. Comentem quando negativam, e não se esqueçam, que não há nada pior no mundo para essas pessoas do que ser ignorado. A minha forma de ver a vida é mesmo essa, fazer o bem sem nunca esperar nada em troca, as vezes até ter coisas más em troca, ser superior a isso.

Comment: Dava +1, se pudesse, por isso "Isso me faz acreditar que: Se alguém faz coisa errada, colherá o que plantou. Comunidades sérias não costumam aceitar esse tipo de comportamento. Aqui é sério. "

Comment: @Wallace, acabo de ver... [Qual é a diferença entre “mas” e “mais”?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/6/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-mas-e-mais#comment345_6)

Comment: @JorgeB. não entendi

Comment: Dead link no final da resposta... :(